# Компоновка Qt в среде Visual Studio 2013

Tags: qt5, qt, visual-studio

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с проблемой компоновки виджетов в Qt. Проблема в том, что большинство уроков и примеров выполнены в/для QtCreator и для студии не подходят.

Пример моего кода с компоновкой (MyClass.cpp):

```
ui.setupUi(this);
QLabel * label = new QLabel(tr("Name:"),this);
label2->show();
QlineEdit *line = new QlineEdit(this);

QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
mainLayout->addWidget(label,0,0);
mainLayout->addWidget(line,1,1);

this->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Получается так, как будто бы компоновки нет, виджет LineEdit перекрывает лэйбл:

[image]

А нужно, как вы поняли, вот так (это прост для примера пикча, QtDesigner не юзаю):

[image]

Слезть со студии не могу, надо что-то решать с ней.

Пример брал отсюда, но он для Creator'a, но суть та же.

[CrosPlatform.ru](http://doc.crossplatform.ru/qt/4.5.0/tutorials-addressbook-part1.html)

Пользую (все qt с оф. сайта):
Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
Qt 5.4.1 msvc2013
Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.4 for Qt5

Привожу весь код:

Main.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyClass w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

MyClass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_myclass.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <Qlineedit>
#include <QGridLayout>

class MyClass : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyClass(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyClass();

private:

    Ui::MyClassClass ui;

};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QLabel * label = new QLabel(tr("Name:"),this);
    label->show();

    QLineEdit * line = new QLineEdit(this);
    line->show();

    QGridLayout * mainLayout = new QGridLayout(this);

    mainLayout->addWidget(label, 0, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(line, 1,1);

    this->setLayout(mainLayout);
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{

}
```

Comment: Приведите весь код, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понятно. QMainWindow имеет свой собственный layout для размещения внутренних элементов, поэтому навязывание своего layout ни к чему не приведет, кроме того, что Вы имеете. Есть два варианта: отнаследовать MyClass от QWidget, либо создать новый виджет, вставить в него все элементы и layout, а затем установить его, как главный виджет:
        setCentralWidget(myWidget);

BTW, а зачем в коде ui.setupUi(this)? Вы, вроде, написали, что не пользуетесь дизайнером

Comment: Спасибо) А setupUi это вроде как указание на форму, при создании проекта qt из студии пишется автоматом.